# Regex remove string in url

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have an url like https://randomsitename-dd555959b114a0.mydomain.com and want to remove the -dd555959b114a0 part of the url.

So randomsitename is a random name and the domain is static domain name.

Is this possible to remove the part with jquery or javascript?

Comment: With JavaScript, yes (jQuery doesn't offer any improvements to regular expressions). Now, where did you get stuck?

Comment: This should work: `yourUrlString.replace(/(https?:\/\/[a-zA-Z]+)-[^-]+(\.mydomain\.com\/?)/, '$1$2')`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this code that is using regex

```
var url = "https://randomsitename-dd555959b114a0.mydomain.com";
var res = url.replace(/ *\-[^.]*\. */g, ".");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VYw9Y/

Answer (score 0):

You could try this regex,

```
(.*)(-[^\.]*)(.*$)
```

Your code should be,

```
var url = "https://randomsitename-dd555959b114a0.mydomain.com";
var res = url.replace(/(.*)(-[^\.]*)(.*$)/, "$1$3");
//=>https://randomsitename.mydomain.com
```

**Explanation:**

- `(.*)` matches any character 0 or more times and it was stored into group 1 because we enclose those characters within paranthesis. Whenever the regex engine finds `-`, it stops storing it into group1.
- `(-[^\.]*)` From `-` upto a literal `.` are stored into group2. It stops storing when it finds a literal dot.
- `(.*$)` From the literal dot upto the last character are stored into group3.
- `$1$3` at the replacement part prints only the stored group1 and 3.

OR

```
(.*)(?:-[^\.]*)(.*$)
```

If you use this regex, in the replacement part you need to put only `$1` and `$2`.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pT7nR8)

Comment: Since capturing is expensive, your second (ignored) capture group would be better as a non-capturing group, i.e. `(?:...)`

Answer (score 0):

It's usually best to code for all possible cases and since hyphens are allowed within any part of domain names, you'll more than likely want to use a more specific RexExp such as:

```
^                  # start of string
(                  # start first capture group
    [a-z]+         # one or more letters
)                  # end first capture group
://                # literal separator
(                  # start second capture group
    [^.-]+         # one or more chars except dot or hyphen
)                  # end second capture group
(?:                # start optional non-capture group
    -              # literal hyphen
    [^.]+          # one or more chars except dot
)?                 # end optional non-capture group
(                  # start third capture group
    .+             # one or more chars
)                  # end third capture group
$                  # end of string
```

Or without comments:

```
^([a-z]+)://([^.-])(?:-[^.]+)?(.+)$
```

(Remember to escape slashes if you use the literal form for RegExps rather than creating them as objects, i.e. `/literal\/form/` vs. `new RegExp('object/form')`)

Used in a string replacement, the second argument should then be: `$1://$2$3`

Previous answers will fail for URLs like `http://foo.bar-baz.com` or `http://foo-bar.baz-blarg.com`.